# Reference implementation of HTML-to-JSON converter for PCG

Tags: c#, html, json, converting, json.net

I have opened [a puzzle at Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47269/html2json-converter). The question is not perceived well (yet) and one of the reasons is that no reference implementation is provided. To mitigate this shortcoming, I have implemented a (non-golfed and documented) reference solution.

I'd like your feedback about

- Correctness according the PCG puzzle specification
- Comprehensibility of the code, e.g. feedback about the documentation

If you can't review everything, please focus on the following points which IMHO could need some attention:

- `ParseHtmlToObjects()`, which is a bit too long for my taste
- `AddProperty()`, which has a `ref` parameter and causes a side effect. If possible, please suggest a better solution, ideally with a code snippet.

I'd not like feedback about:

- Performance, since it is ok with the largest real world test file I have
- Converting loops to LINQ, since I simply prefer the loops
- Other nifty C# 10.5 lambda inline tricks etc. that nobody can read 6 months from now

The environment:

- Implementation language is C# 4.5
- Input is HTML, output is JSON
- Libraries: HtmlAgilityPack, ExCSS and JSON.NET
- Implemented with R# support. The code is almost green with warnings about "Possible multiple enumeration" inside `Convert()`. Maybe someone can elaborate how critical that is.

The task:

- Read some awkward and verbose HTML document, extract the relevant information based on various indicators (HTML elements, attributes and CSS style information)
- Output valid JSON which contains the relevant information

For more details please see [the question at PCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47269/html2json-converter).

The major part of the code:

- Entry point is the constructor `HtmlToJsonConverter()`
- `Convert()` method

I don't provide `CustomJsonConverter` here, since that is straightforward.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using ExCSS;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace QADirector
{
    internal class HtmlToJsonConverter
    {
        private readonly FileInfo _inputFile;
        private readonly FileInfo _outputFile;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an object that can convert a QA Director HTML export to a JSON object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">HTML report to be converted.</param>
        /// <param name="destination">JSON file name to be created</param>
        public HtmlToJsonConverter(FileInfo source, FileInfo destination)
        {
            _outputFile = destination;
            _inputFile = source;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the HTML input file into JSON and writes the output file
        /// </summary>
        public void Convert()
        {
            var htmlDocument = ReadFileToHtmlDocument();

            var pages = GetPages(htmlDocument);
            Debug.WriteLine("Found {0} pages", pages.Count());

            var objects = ParseHtmlToObjects(pages);
            WriteJson(objects);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Write the object as JSON using a custom converter that
        /// correctly writes the property list as single properties
        /// and not as a list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Object to be serialized</param>
        private void WriteJson(DataObject obj)
        {
            var converter = new CustomJsonConverter();
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented, converter);
            File.WriteAllText(_outputFile.FullName, data);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the HTML pages and creates an equivalent object by parsing the properties and values
        /// as well as the properties and values of the sub items
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pages">HTML pages to be analyzed. <see cref="GetPages"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>An object containing properties and child objects.</returns>
        private static DataObject ParseHtmlToObjects(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> pages)
        {
            var rootObject = new DataObject();
            var currentObject = rootObject;
            // Go through all pages
            foreach (var page in pages)
            {
                // Analyze all the span tags
                var steps = page.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Name == "span")).ToList();
                string key = null;
                foreach (var step in steps)
                {
                    if (!IsKey(step))
                    {
                        // If this is not a key, the key was detected before. Use it to populate the object
                        currentObject = AddProperty(currentObject, key, GetTextFromSpan(step));
                        key = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (key != null)
                        {
                            // Special case: we detected a new key, although the old key has not been used as property yet
                            // This can happen for keys without value, so add it empty.
                            currentObject = AddProperty(currentObject, key, "");
                        }


                        key = GetKeyFromNode(step);
                        var level = GetIndentationFromNode(step);
                        if (level == currentObject.level)
                        {
                            // Still the same level.
                            // Remain at the same object in order to add more properties.
                        }
                        else if (level > currentObject.level)
                        {
                            // Decend to lower level: create a new child
                            var child = new DataObject {level = level, Parent = currentObject};
                            currentObject.Children.Add(child);
                            currentObject = child;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Move up until level is equal
                            while (level < currentObject.level)
                            {
                                currentObject = currentObject.Parent;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return rootObject;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a property to an object.
        /// If that property already exists, create a new object and add the property there
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Object to add the property to</param>
        /// <param name="key">Name of the property</param>
        /// <param name="value">Value of the property</param>
        /// <returns>The same object if the property did not exist yet, the new object if the property already existed</returns>
        private static DataObject AddProperty(DataObject obj, string key, string value)
        {
            // Special case: <Span> which contains the page information. Skip it.
            if (key == null) return obj; 

            if (obj.Properties.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                // This key was already assigned, so this must be a new object on the same level
                var sibling = new DataObject {level = obj.level, Parent = obj.Parent};
                obj.Parent.Children.Add(sibling);
                obj = sibling;
            }

            obj.Properties.Add(key, value);
            return obj;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the indentation from the HTML node.
        /// Detection is done via the left CSS style of the HTML element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="step">HTML node to analyze</param>
        /// <returns>Indentation value, 0 if no left attribute was found</returns>
        private static decimal GetIndentationFromNode(HtmlNode step)
        {
            decimal thisIndent=0;
            var styleSheet = ExtractStyle(step);
            foreach (var cssAttribute in styleSheet.StyleRules[0].Declarations)
            {
                if (cssAttribute.Name != "left") continue;

                var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo {NumberDecimalSeparator = "."};
                thisIndent = decimal.Parse(cssAttribute.Term.ToString().Replace("in", ""), numberFormatInfo);
                Debug.WriteLine("Left attribute found:" + cssAttribute.Term);
            }
            return thisIndent;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if the node contains a key and if so, return its text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="span">HTML SPAN node to be analyzed</param>
        /// <returns>Text of the key if key was detected, <c>null</c> otherwise. 
        /// Text is cleaned from HTML entities and has the trailing colon removed.</returns>
        private static string GetKeyFromNode(HtmlNode span)
        {
            return IsKey(span) ? GetTextFromSpan(span).Trim(':') : null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if the node contains a key.
        /// Detection is done via the <c>font-weight="bold"</c> CSS style of the HTML element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="span">HTML SPAN node to be analyzed</param>
        /// <returns><c>True</c> if font-weight was bold, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        private static bool IsKey(HtmlNode span)
        {
            var styleSheet = ExtractStyle(span);
            foreach (var cssAttribute in styleSheet.StyleRules[0].Declarations)
            {
                if (cssAttribute.Name != "font-weight" || cssAttribute.Term.ToString() != "bold") continue;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the text from a HTML SPAN element. 
        /// This includes removal of the <c>NOBR</c> tag and decoding of HTML special characters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="span">SPAN element to get the text from.</param>
        /// <returns>Inner text of the SPAN node</returns>
        private static string GetTextFromSpan(HtmlNode span)
        {
            var text = span.Descendants("nobr").First().InnerText; // There is only one <nobr>
            text = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
            return text;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts the information of the <c>style</c> attribute
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="element">HTML element to extract the style information from</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static StyleSheet ExtractStyle(HtmlNode element)
        {
            var rawStyle = element.Attributes["style"].Value;
            var styleSheet = new Parser().Parse(String.Format(".dummy{{{0}}}", rawStyle));
            return styleSheet;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the pages, identified by a DIV element defining the width and height
        /// inside another DIV element 
        /// (the one with style="page-break-inside:avoid;page-break-after:always;")
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="htmlDocument">HTML to analyze</param>
        /// <returns>DIV nodes corresponding to pages, using the inner of the described DIVs (the one defining width and height)</returns>
        private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetPages(HtmlDocument htmlDocument)
        {
            var pages =
                htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                    .Where(x =>(x.Name == "div" && x.Ancestors("div").Count() == 1));
            return pages;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads the file contents from disk and converts it into a HTML document
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>HTML document as read from disk</returns>
        private HtmlDocument ReadFileToHtmlDocument()
        {
            var source = File.ReadAllText(_inputFile.FullName);
            var html = new HtmlDocument();
            html.LoadHtml(source);
            return html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A code golfer has been converted to the light side of the force? Pinch me someone, this almost sound to good to be true!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `IsKey()` method I go with [@mjolka](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/44723/mjolka) and also you prefer loops I will suggest to use `Any()` like

```
private static bool IsKey(HtmlNode span)
{
    var styleSheet = ExtractStyle(span);
    bool isKey = styleSheet.StyleRules[0].Declarations
                      .Any(cssAttribute.Name == "font-weight" && cssAttribute.Term.ToString() == "bold");

    return isKey;
}
```

because it really is the same and it is more obvious what is meant.

---

In the `GetIndentationFromNode()` method, there should be only one `cssAttribute` with the name `left` so you should `break` out of the loop after you have found the value.

---

You should let your variables some space to breathe. Instead of e.g `decimal thisIndent=0;` you better should write `decimal thisIndent = 0;`, because this will make your code more readable.

---

In the `ParseHtmlToObjects()` method there is no need to call `ToList()` on the `IEnumerable<>` here `page.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Name == "span")).ToList();`.

Always code against interfaces if the implementation isn't needed.

If `step` isn't a key you can by adding a `continue;` omit the `else` and therefor save horizontal spacing.

By removing the `if (level == currentObject.level)` condition you can shorten the code.

By ectracting the analyzing of the `Descendants` of the current `page` this method can be shortened and be more readable.

By extracting the `while` loop to equalize the level to a meaningful method, you can omit the comment also this is only a cosmetic change.

The check `if (key != null)` could be omitted, because if `key == null` the `AddProperty()` method just returns the passed in `DataObject`.

Applying these points lead to

```
private static DataObject ParseHtmlToObjects(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> pages)
{
    var rootObject = new DataObject();
    var currentObject = rootObject;

    foreach (var page in pages)
    {
        var steps = page.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Name == "span")).ToList();
        currentObject = AnalyzeSpanTags(steps, currentObject);
    }

    return rootObject;
}

private static DataObject AnalyzeSpanTags(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> steps, DataObject currentObject)
{
    string key = null;
    foreach (var step in steps)
    {
        if (!IsKey(step))
        {
            // If this is not a key, the key was detected before. Use it to populate the object
            currentObject = AddProperty(currentObject, key, GetTextFromSpan(step));
            key = null;
            continue;
        }

        // Special case: Maybe we detected a new key, although the old key has not been used as property yet
        // This can happen for keys without value, so add it empty.
        currentObject = AddProperty(currentObject, key, "");

        key = GetKeyFromNode(step);
        var level = GetIndentationFromNode(step);

        if (level > currentObject.level)
        {
            // Decend to lower level: create a new child
            var child = new DataObject { level = level, Parent = currentObject };
            currentObject.Children.Add(child);
            currentObject = child;
        }
        else
        {
            currentObject = EqualizeLevel(currentObject, level);
        }
    }
    return currentObject;
}

private static DataObject EqualizeLevel(DataObject obj, decimal level)
{
    while (level < obj.level)
    {
        obj = obj.Parent;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

---

Speaking about comments. Comments should describe **why** something is done. You should let the code speak for itself about **what** is done.

So comments like

> ```
> // Go through all pages
> foreach (var page in pages)
> ```

are superfluous, because they don't add any value.

---

By introducing a `GetAddedSiblingIfKeyExists()` method (the name is not that optimal, but I couldn't come up with a better one) like

```
private static DataObject GetAddedSiblingIfKeyExists(DataObject obj, string key)
{
    if (key == null || !obj.Properties.ContainsKey(key)) { return obj; }

    var sibling = new DataObject { level = obj.level, Parent = obj.Parent };
    obj.Parent.Children.Add(sibling);
    return sibling;
}
```

the `AddProperty()` method would result in

```
private static DataObject AddProperty(DataObject obj, string key, string value)
{
    // Special case: <Span> which contains the page information. Skip it.
    if (key == null) return obj;

    obj.Properties.Add(key, value);
    return obj;
}
```

which would change the `AnalyzeSpanTags()` method like

```
private static DataObject AnalyzeSpanTags(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> steps, DataObject currentObject)
{
    string key = null;
    foreach (var step in steps)
    {
        currentObject = GetAddedSiblingIfKeyExists(currentObject, key);

        if (!IsKey(step))
        {
        .....
```

maybe `GetAddedSiblingForExistingKey()` would be a little bit more meaningful.

---

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the HTML input file into JSON and writes the output file
    /// </summary>
    public void Convert()
```

the xml documentation clearly states that this method is doing to much.

The method is reading the htmlfile, converting the content to JSON and writing the JSON to the output file.
I wouldn't expect that a method named `Convert()` is writing to a file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time and dissecting it to that extent! This is great feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This is confusing:

> ```
> foreach (var cssAttribute in styleSheet.StyleRules[0].Declarations)
> {
>     if (cssAttribute.Name != "font-weight" || cssAttribute.Term.ToString() != "bold") continue;
>     return true;
> }
> return false;
> ```

I think this is clearer

```
foreach (var cssAttribute in styleSheet.StyleRules[0].Declarations)
{
    if (cssAttribute.Name == "font-weight" && cssAttribute.Term.ToString() == "bold")
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

I would recommend using `Any`, but as you mentioned, you prefer loops.